# NSRunningApplication bundleIdentifier locks my asynchronous app

Tags: objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, appkit

I am retrieving an `NSRunningApplication`'s `bundleIdentifier` in a background thread served by GCD, the code I am using basically looks like this:

```
NSWorkspace * __block workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    NSString *dateString = nil;
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // here's where my app is getting locked
    [foo doTheDinosaurWithAppName:[[workspace frontmostApplication] bundleIdentifier];
});
```

The problem I am facing is that at random times this call will choke the task and won't let it complete, this will happen in various threads until I reach the point where I have more than 64 locked threads and my application is terminated because I have exceeded the limit.

When looking at the process' information using Activity Monitor, I got the following trace repeated about 67 times (among many other things):

```
2317 Thread_5990845   DispatchQueue_4: com.apple.root.low-priority  (concurrent)
+ 2317 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8e9d0fb9]
+   2317 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 314  [0x7fff8e9cdef8]
+     2317 _dispatch_worker_thread2  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 40  [0x7fff90678177]
+       2317 _dispatch_root_queue_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 326  [0x7fff90677082]
+         2317 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff9067528d]
+           2317 _dispatch_call_block_and_release  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 12  [0x7fff906781bb]
+             2317 __45-[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]_block_invoke_2  (in XXXXXXXXX) + 251  [0x10bc7075b]  AppDelegate.m:180
+               2317 -[NSRunningApplication bundleIdentifier]  (in AppKit) + 96  [0x7fff937d8468]
+                 2317 -[NSLock lock]  (in Foundation) + 145  [0x7fff962428bb]
+                   2317 _pthread_mutex_lock  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 372  [0x7fff8e9cf779]
+                     2317 __psynch_mutexwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8efc2746]
```

If you look at the 9th line you can see what I am talking about.

Following Ken's advice, there are a few traces (maybe 6) that look a bit different, but they all seem to point to the same line:

```
2317 Thread_5993821   DispatchQueue_4: com.apple.root.low-priority  (concurrent)
+ 2317 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8e9d0fb9]
+   2317 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 314  [0x7fff8e9cdef8]
+     2317 _dispatch_worker_thread2  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 40  [0x7fff90678177]
+       2317 _dispatch_root_queue_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 326  [0x7fff90677082]
+         2317 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff9067528d]
+           2317 _dispatch_call_block_and_release  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 12  [0x7fff906781bb]
+             2317 __45-[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]_block_invoke_2  (in Keystats) + 251  [0x10bc7075b]  AppDelegate.m:180
+               2317 -[NSRunningApplication bundleIdentifier]  (in AppKit) + 164  [0x7fff937d84ac]
+                 2317 -[NSRunningApplication _fetchStaticInformationWithAtLeastKey:]  (in AppKit) + 94  [0x7fff93565a97]
+                   2317 _LSCopyApplicationInformation  (in LaunchServices) + 2214  [0x7fff8f165adf]
+                     2317 LSClientToServerConnection::LSClientToServerConnection(int, __CFDictionary const*, bool)  (in LaunchServices) + 255  [0x7fff8f161543]
+                       2317 LSClientToServerConnection::setupServerConnection(int, __CFDictionary const*)  (in LaunchServices) + 160  [0x7fff8f1616f4]
+                         2317 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync  (in libxpc.dylib) + 195  [0x7fff9a75f7ef]
+                           2317 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 206  [0x7fff906799f9]
+                             2317 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8efbea56]
```

I don't know if this is a bug in `NSRunningApplication`'s `bundleIdentifier` or if I am missing something with my use of `dispatch_async`.

I am running this code in OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the main thread as workspace isn't documented as thread safe?

Comment: What are the other threads doing? Are you letting the main thread run the event loop?

Comment: @Wain NSWorkspace works fine for the most part (in a background thread) it is just rare cases where this happens.

Comment: @KenThomases All the other threads are doing the same thing, they get the frontmost application's bundle id and then process it in the same way. I am letting the main thread run the event loop I am not running anything in the main thread (aside from GUI changes).

Comment: Are they all blocked in **exactly** the same place? Presumably, something successfully locked that lock that the others are trying to lock, but then went on and got stuck elsewhere. You want to find that one different one to see where it's stuck. (It is possible that there's a bug that caused the thread which locked it to fail to unlock it even if it didn't get stuck. But I'd rate that as a lower probability.)

Comment: @KenThomases I've updated my question with the one trace that looks "a bit" different from the others, though it basically points to the same line as the others. Unfortunately I don't know how to interpret that extra information.

Comment: That looks like it's communicating with a Launch Services server process. For some reason, that's not responding in a timely manner. There may be something messed up with your account. Can you reproduce the problem on another account or another machine? Also, in the sample report there's a list of loaded images. Ones with a plus (`+`) are non-Apple. Are there any that are also not from your app and its support libraries/frameworks? That would be third-party software that loads itself into every app process. Those can cause trouble.

Comment: Sadly I don't have a deterministic way to reproduce this, even though this action gets executed correctly tens of thousands of times per day, there's random ocassions when the thread gets locked and it crashes the app. Thanks for the *pointers*.

Comment: For clarification, you don't _need_ to get the frontmost application's bundle identifier from multiple threads simultaneously, right? That seems to be just a side effect of the `bundleIdentifier` call taking more time than the time between calls to whatever method contains the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

NSWorkspace is thread safe for *specific* methods.  `-frontmostApplication` is not one of them.  Go to [NSWorkspace Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  and look at the Discussion for each method.

Notice that `+sharedWorkspace`, `-openFile:`, `-openURL:`, etc explicitly state: "It is safe to call this method from any thread in your app in OS X v10.6 and later."

`-frontmostApplication` and others lack the thread-safety notice.  They are currently thread unsafe.

Just because an API is thread-unsafe doesn't mean that it's 100% going to hang when you call it on a background thread.  It's going to behave exactly as you are seeing: it's going to work most of the time, and occasionally deadlock.

<s>You need to only call frontmostApplication on the main thread.</s>

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    __block NSString *bundleIdentifier;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         bundleIdentifier = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication] bundleIdentifier];
    });

    [foo doTheDinosaurWithAppName:bundleIdentifier];
});
```

<s>Note: This fixes the NSWorkspace issue, but you may have other threading issues in `-doTheDinosaurWithAppName:`.</s>

*Edit: Actually, Ken is right (see comment below).*

While everything I said above is true, my example code also reproduces the issue fairly quickly.  `--[NSRunningApplication bundleIdentifier]` is making a synchronous IPC call out to the launch services daemon, and I'm easily able to saturate that connection if I start querying for bundleIDs each run loop iteration.

If I only query for the bundleID 100 times a second, everything works fine.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm normally a stickler for relying only on documented promises of thread safety, too. However, `-runningApplications` is documented as thread-safe and all properties of `NSRunningApplication`, including `active`, are documented as thread-safe. So, it would be fairly trivial to implement `-frontmostApplication` in a thread-safe manner. Also, the hang being observed is inside `NSRunningApplication` code, so `-frontmostApplication` apparently worked and it is something inside `NSRunningApplication` that is broken, even though that is supposed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Actually, you are correct.  Good call.  When I made an example project with my code, it exhibits the same issue.  If you start asking for a bundleID each run loop cycle, items get queued up faster than the ls daemon (which -bundleIdentifier is ultimately blocking on) can reply.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome discussion! Not sure if I should mark this question as answered, because it seems like this may be a bug. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, I feel like the issue isn't quite answered yet.  Can you post a bit more code on how often you are calling the block which calls `-bundleIdentifier`?  If you are calling it each run loop iteration regardless, you definitely are in a situation where the queue can be accumulating over time.